# "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API" when searching for a location

Tags: bug, status-completed, salary-calculator

See this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz7qe_olclTwLURZSUx5ZF9iOUk/view?usp=sharing

It looks like there's a problem with the Google Maps API daily request quota. Nothing appears when typing in the field.

Comment: please inline your screenshot, you got enough rep for that

Comment: And use the proper screenshot feature instead of that awful files.fm service please :)

Comment: It might have to do with: *Based on the amount of data we received in the survey results, the initial release has limited salaries to the United States, Canada, the United Kingdom, France, and Germany*

Comment: We just DDOS-es Google ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Salary Calculator location issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356768/salary-calculator-location-issue)

Comment: @JohnM.Wright that question is closed as a dupe of this one

Comment: Timing -- that one got hit first :)

Comment: @DavidG in once screenshot i couldnt reproduce whole thing, that's why i used  temporary video-upload.

Answer (score 4):

We have just pushed a temporary fix to mitigate the issue. The input field has been replaced with a dropdown.

It's definitely not an ideal solution, and **it is meant to be temporary.**

We'll re-enable the text input and autocomplete as soon as we resolve the quota issue.

Comment: This is also affecting jobs: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Comment: @Jonathan Indeed, it also affected /jobs because it used the same out-of-quota Google Maps key. This is now resolved.

Answer (score 2):

After much gnashing of teeth, listening to hold music and modifying some code paths, we've re-enabled the autocomplete feature. (And made a few other improvements based on user feedback).