# Salary Calculator location issue

Tags: bug, salary-calculator

I can't set my location with the intellisense or dropdown, is not showed:
[image]

I see that the maps api quota has exceeded:
[image]

Writing eg. Canada is working well.

Comment: from the announcement: *Based on the amount of data we received in the survey results, the initial release has limited salaries to the United States, Canada, the United Kingdom, France, and Germany*

Comment: @NathanOliver yep I read it now, I tried using Canada and is working fine, but the Google api issue persist